# Linear decay raised to power?

Tags: exponential-function, exponentiation

I have a phenomenon whose range is described as

$$range(t) = \left(1 - \frac{t}{T} \right)^b$$

where $t \in [0, T]$, and $b$ defines the speed of the decay.

Does this form of decay have a name, and how is it related to exponential decay?

Comment: It is called polynomial decay. This is the case even when $b$ is not integer, as the decay is bounded by actual polynomials.

Comment: @PaulSinclair: thank you